# How to compare the particular columns of 2 CSV files through python

Tags: csv, comparison, python-2.6

Python version - 2.6.6

**1.csv**

```
10.10.1.1,Web server,test,http,Running
10.10.1.1,Web server,test,http1,Running
```

**2.csv**

```
10.10.1.1,Web server,test,http,Not Running
10.10.1.1,Web server,test,http1,Not Running
```

I have tried with below code to compare the 2 csv files for particular columns but it doesn't work. I need the output as per actual result, please guide on below

```
import csv
s=open('1.csv')
checkit = csv.reader(s)
for c in checkit:
    o=open('2.csv')
    csv_o = csv.reader(o)
    for row in csv_o:
        if (row[4] == c[4]) and (row[0] == c[0]):
            print 'equal =',row[0],',',row[3],',',row[4]
        else:
            print 'Differenece =',row[0],',',row[3],',',row[4]
```

**Actual result is**

```
Difference = 10.10.1.1, http,Not Running
Difference = 10.10.1.1, http1,Not Running
Difference = 10.10.1.1, http,Not Running
Difference = 10.10.1.1, http1,Not Running
```

**expected result is**

```
Difference = 10.10.1.1, http,Not Running
Difference = 10.10.1.1, http1,Not Running
```

Need to write expected result in different csv. Please help